# PWA with Websockets in angular

Tags: angular

I have a angular application that includes Websockets to communicate  and now my task to convert that application into a PWA will my service worker support websocket?
If yes how do i?

I tried to add Wesocket Url in my ngsw-config.json under DataGroups and tried to run it in offline mode.
Is that the correct way?